# How to get the ActualWidth without scrollbar of a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a `DataTemplate` for `ListView` items. Inside this `DataTemplate`, I have a `Grid` control for which I need the actual width of the `ListView` but without the width of the ScrollBar, because then some content gets behind the scrollbar. I cant use the width of `ListViewItem`s because I am defining it with this template. I saw some answers here for WPF with Ancestors, but I think that is not possible in WinRT.

EDIT:
I have tried getting the listview's scrollviewer ViewportWidth. here is the code I got

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
      <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ContainerViewportWidthConverter}}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>...
```

this is the DataTemplate that my listview is using and its in a seperate xaml file.

the converter looks like this:

```
        if (!(value is FrameworkElement)) return null;
        var ctrl = value as FrameworkElement;
        var scrollViewer = ctrl.GetFirstAncestorOfType<ScrollViewer>();
        return scrollViewer.ViewportWidth;
```

the scrollViewer becomes always `null` and the app crashes
when i try to get all the ancestors or descendants, the returning list is also empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth`?

Comment: I tried, but I'm a beginner so I dont know how to get the reference of the listviews ScrollViewer, and I dont know how to bind to it in XAML either.

Comment: The easy answer is to use WinRT XAML Toolkit, but you can find more ways to find a `ScrollViewer` from the control template using `VisualTreeHelper`. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408408/how-do-you-programatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-textbox-in-winrt) for example.

Comment: I have tried your approach, and I cant get it to work. I edited my question to be more specific. Maybe you could give me advice where to put this code if a converter is not a good idea.

Comment: I think putting the VisualTreeHelper call in a converter for a DataTemplate isn't going to work because the binding is probably first evaluated before the item is added to the visual tree. You will probably need to handle the SizeChanged event for your ListView and check the dimensions at that time. At that point you can update a property in the view model and make your DataTemplate bind its Width to that property. You might probably need to time-throttle it if size change events occur frequently. That said - does your ListView get resized at all? Usually they don't and constant Width works.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a property to bind to and i set it in the code behind.